# Girl gets summoned to another world and marries demon king

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It’s a manga where a girl is isekai’d and eventually marries the demon king. They meet in dreams and there’s a whole thing about how she was the only one who knew the demon king’s true name. The girl may also be a Saintess, but I’m not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Does she marry the demon king early in the story (like within the first 3-5 chapters), or is this something that happens at the end?

Comment: It happens closer to the end of the story, around chapter 40 if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

*[In Another World I'm Called the "Black Healer"](https://myanimelist.net/manga/86043/Isekai_de_Kuro_no_Iyashi_Te_tte_Yobareteimasu)*

> Quickly making a name for herself as an unparalleled healer—earning
> the title "Black Healer"—Kanzaki sets out on an adventure in this
> fantastical world, searching for a way home and, all the while,
> unraveling the truth behind the **mysterious man in her dreams**.